# AngularJS: getting values from nested ng-repeat form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to `AngularJS`, I successfully designed the repeated forms using nested `ng-repeat`. But I can't find the right way to get all values corresponding to the forms.

**Here is my updated JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/MrSuS/gTc5v/7/

**Update:** And you can see, radio input is also not working properly.

Answer (score 2):

there is no binding in your application use ng-model to bind your field values.

if you want to design custom form depends on your dynamic data you should write a directive like this [Example Form Directive](http://nimbly.github.io/angular-formly/#!/)

**UPDATE**

I think best way is repeat html form in your position.
It is simple, easy and less code...

```
<div ng-repeat="form in forms">
    <h2>{{form.name}}</h2>
    <input type="text" ng-model="form.answer.city"><br/>
    ...
```

here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wZbQ6/2/) example...

Comment: thanks for the example. It looks great. But it has only one form. And I have multiple forms, if i use `ng-model` on a element inside `ng-repeat` it shows same answer for all forms. Because `ng-model` binding will be same for all forms.

Comment: my goal is, if user wants to fill two or more forms for different persons then I should be able to get separate form values. you can check my updated `JSFiddle`. It must show all values one by one in alert.

Comment: thanks for the answer and your valuable time. But I forgot to tell you that the `$scope.forms` can have multiple forms. It changes dynamically. Sometimes size of `$scope.forms` can be 3 and sometimes only 1.

Comment: if we are talking about spamming same forms length does not matter... this solution can work for every length of the form array... try to add form as many as you want it will work...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49016/discussion-between-wicky26-and-mrsus)

Comment: sorry I forgot to update link in my update section pls check this again http://jsfiddle.net/wZbQ6/2/

Comment: Thanks i made it work, the `angular.copy` helped me. remember i mentioned earlier that it shows same values for all forms, actually i was doing wrong. For others, i will post the working `JSFiddle` of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly use `ng-model` for binding. Second, use `$index` as array subscript for your `ng-model`

```
 ng-model="input[$index]"
```

Comment: got your idea, but not working properly. You can check my updated `JSFiddle`.